# Use of the article

Tags: articles

> You can place an order with payment that will be made in March.

> You can place an order with the payment that will be made in March.

I am trying to say that you can place an order and you will make the payment for this order in March. Does the meaning changes if don't use the artice ''the''?

Comment: Both are clumsy, the first perhaps slightly better. You seem to ask a lot of questions that depend on business 'jargonese'. You'd probably be better to learn the real jargon - in this case possibly "deferred payment terms".

Comment: … or the consumer advertising versions, "buy now, pay later', "nothing to pay until March" etc